# Admin all menu access denied

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, permissions, acl, admin-user

I removed the main "admin" module permission for my admin user from Magento backend. After the changes were saved, the entire admin page now shows "access denied".

How can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: i got the answer from this .http://iamrookie.com/blog/19/access-denied-issue-in-magento.html

Answer (score 1):

[Atwix posted on their blog how to create an admin user](http://www.atwix.com/magento/reset-admin-password-mysql/)

You can read from the query, how the ACL works and how to fix it on mysql level

```
SET @fistname = 'Fabian';
SET @lastname = 'Blechschmidt';
SET @email = 'mailaddress@example.com';
SET @username = 'fabian';
SET @password = 'password';
SET @salt = 'Fl';

INSERT INTO admin_user
SELECT
NULL user_id,
@fistname firstname,
@lastname lastname,
@email email,
@username username,
CONCAT(MD5(CONCAT(@salt, @password)), ':', @salt) password,
NOW( ) created,
NULL modified,
NULL logdate,
0 lognum,
0 reload_acl_flag,
1 is_active,
(SELECT MAX(extra) FROM admin_user WHERE extra IS NOT NULL) extra,
NULL rp_token,
NOW() rp_token_created_at;

INSERT INTO admin_role
SELECT
NULL role_id,
(SELECT role_id FROM admin_role WHERE role_name = 'Administrators') parent_id,
2 tree_level,
0 sort_order,
'U' role_type,
(SELECT user_id FROM admin_user WHERE username = @username) user_id,
@username role_name
```

[Code is a little bit changed and from here](http://blog.fabian-blechschmidt.de/add-amin-user/)

Answer (score 0):

If you use the command line tool [magerun](http://magerun.net/) you can create a new admin user with full permissions with

```
n98-magerun.phar admin:user:create [username] [email] [password] [firstname] [lastname]
```